# Parallel.ForEach over a BlockingCollection stops blocking after length of time

Tags: c#, parallel.foreach, blockingcollection

I have a windows service that is processing some records from a database queue table. The number of queue records is highly variable. Sometimes a lot, sometimes none. In addition the length of time it takes to process a record from the queue is highly variable.

I would like to implement a producer/consumer so that the processing of the records does not block the retrieval of additional queue records to process. My code looks like below. If my service went 5 minutes or so without processing any records, and then a record to process showed up in the database, it was retrieved, added to the collection, and processed without issue. But if a longer amount of time elapsed, say 30 minutes, the service was still alive but would not pick up or process any records.

My assumption is that at some point my consumer stops blocking and the method is allowed to fall through and the background producer thread is then ignored.

Is there a time interval where the consumer will stop blocking? Or something else within the code that is being handled incorrectly?

```
var recordsToRun = new BlockingCollection<T>();
//producer
Task.Run(async () =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        //go get the records

        foreach(var record in retrievedRecords)
        {
            recordsToRun.Add(record);

            await Task.Delay(100);
        }     
    }
});

//consumer
Parallel.ForEach(recordsToRun.GetConsumingPartitioner(), rec =>
    {
            //process the record
    });
```

Comment: My guess is that there was some sort of unhandled exception that killed one of your threads.

Comment: I think you mean `recordsToRun.GetConsumingEnumerable()` instead of `recordsToRun.GetConsumingPartitioner()`

Comment: I agree with @Jacob, try some logging and a wrapping try-catch to see if there are any exceptions. Also for the producer consider using a long running task e.g....`Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ..., TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);`

Comment: @MaYaN - I meant GetConsumingPartioner. I have seen that recommended over GetConsumingEnumerable for use with a Parallel.ForEach. On mobile so I don't have the links handy.

Comment: @Jacob - I'll throw some more logging into the process to see if that is the case. I haven't used this logic before so I wanted to rule out a misunderstanding of the logic on my part.

Comment: There is no timeout on threads of `Parallel.ForEach()`, or anything like that. There is something going on in the code you didn't show. You will either have to debug your program, or reduce it to an [mcve] and show us that.